# Using TestRestTemplate to authenticate in a Spring boot app with Spring security formLogin()

Tags: websecurity

I am trying the solution suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458272/21604051.

My test looks like this:

```
@Test
@Order(7)
    public void when7useSecureRestTemplate_shouldSucceedWith200() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("in when7useSecureRestTemplate_shouldSucceedWith200()");
        HttpHeaders loginHdrs = new HttpHeaders();
        loginHdrs.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
        loginHdrs.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        form.set("username", username);
        form.set("password", secret);
        ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse =
            secureTestRestTemplate().postForEntity(loginUrl, new HttpEntity<>(form, loginHdrs), String.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, loginResponse.getStatusCode());
        HttpHeaders respHeaders = loginResponse.getHeaders();
        Set<String> hdrKeys = respHeaders.keySet();
        for (String key : hdrKeys) LOG.info(String.format("Header key: %s, value: %s", key, respHeaders.get(key)));
        LOG.info(loginResponse.getBody());
    }
```

The testresttemplate is created like this:

```
private TestRestTemplate secureTestRestTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new TestRestTemplate("user", "user_pasword@321.home", HttpClientOption.SSL, HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS, HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES);
    }
```

Simple enough and it works just like suggested in the referenced answer. But it **only works if the password** **is exactly "password"**. Any other password fails. Basically, no matter what value is set in the MultiValueMap, the authenticator ends up with "password". I suspect this has to do with the form input type (which is also password).

Here is the html form (created by Spring Boot)

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <p>
          <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Here is my Spring Security Config:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("In filterChain()");
        http.requiresChannel(channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure())
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests( 
                    requests -> { requests
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/login", "/oauth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        })
        .formLogin().permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/XXXX/welcome", true)
        .failureUrl("/XXXX/access-denied")
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/XXXX/logout");
        /*
        http.oauth2Login().loginPage("/login")
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(oauth2UserService)
            .and()
            .successHandler(googleAuthSuccessHandler());
            */              
        return http.build();
    }
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Tried this

```
    static String username = "user";
    static String secret = "user_pasword@xxx.yyy";
```

Ended up with this messsage from the customAuthnticationProvider:

2023-05-15T19:41:26.985-07:00  INFO 27552 --- [o-auto-1-exec-2] o.e.xxx.CustomAuthenticationProvider  : Authenticating: user

2023-05-15T19:41:26.985-07:00  INFO 27552 --- [o-auto-1-exec-2] o.xxx.xxx.SecurityConfiguration   : In loadUserByUsername() --> user

Hibernate: select r1_0.id,r1_0.date_create,r1_0.email,r1_0.enabled,r1_0.first_name,r1_0.last_name,r1_0.password,r1_0.provider,r1_0.roles,r1_0.user_name from rpmuser r1_0 where r1_0.user_name=?

2023-05-15T19:41:27.061-07:00  INFO 27552 --- [o-auto-1-exec-2] o.e.xxx.CustomAuthenticationProvider  : Password mismatch: **password** -- $2a$10$moe8P1/ALLbRWsCHtt7DyO0QaxDUIrWZ5Mymq/ixW8031vOvFuWLy

[E

This is the class that produced the message:

```
public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {}
    
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        LOG.info(String.format("Authenticating: %s", authentication.getName()));
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();
        if (!(credentials instanceof String)) return null;
        String rawPassword =  credentials.toString();
        UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, user.getPassword())) {
            LOG.info(String.format("Password mismatch: %s -- %s", rawPassword, user.getPassword()));
            throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("mismatched passwords: $s and %s", user.getPassword(), rawPassword));
        }
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, rawPassword, authorities);
}
```